# Prevent kafka consumer from timing out for long process

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I need to prevent the kafka consumer from timing out while the application waits for a particular process to complete. My approach is to pause the partitions and then resume them once the process is completed.

```
List<TopicPartition> partitionList = new ArrayList<>(); 
partitionList.addAll(kafkaConsumer.assignment());
kafkaConsumer.pause(partitionList);

while(//waiting for the process to complete){
    Thread.sleep(10000);                            
    kafkaConsumer.poll(0);
}
kafkaConsumer.resume(partitionList);
```

Questions

Does pause send heartbeat to kafka automatically or should I still need to poll at regular intervals to send the heart beat?

Is mine the best approach ? or is there a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since Kafka 0.10.1, consumers do have a background thread for sending heartbeats: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-62%3A+Allow+consumer+to+send+heartbeats+from+a+background+thread

Thus, you don't need to call `poll()` to send heartbeat to the brokers. However, there is a second timeout `max.poll.interval.ms` -- you must call `poll()` within this time to avoid this second timeout. Default value is 5 minutes. You can just increase this timeout if your wait is even longer than this. If you do so, you also don't need to pause any partitions etc.

If you are using an older version, you approach of pausing, and calling `poll()` regularly is the only way to send regular heartbeat to avoid the timeout.

**Note:** increasing `max.poll.interval.ms` implies a higher timeout for rebalances, too, ie, if a rebalance is started, each group member has this amount of time to re-join the consumer group before it would be removed from the group by the broker side group coordinator.

Comment: @ Matthias J. Sax : Thanks for the response .Unfortunately we are on kafka version 0.10.0 and has to go with my initial approach. In kafka version 0.10.1 onwards can we set heartbeat.interval.ms so that kafka consumer is kept alive automatically ? If heartbeat.interval.ms<max.poll.interval.ms, then session time out scenario will not occur, right ?

Comment: I increased max.poll.interval.ms to do exactly the same - this is helpful.